# Creating instances from classes

Tags: javascript, terminology

I have seen two ways of creating instances:

Method 1

```
function Contact(first, last) {
this.firstName = first;
this.lastName = last;
this.fullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };
}
```

Method 2

```
var Associate = function(first, last) {
this.firstName = first;
this.lastName = last;
this.fullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };
};
```

Are there any benefits of the first over the other?

What is the correct terminology for these?  I believe they are supposed to be called "Object Constructor Functions" but I have also seen them called classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate question and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 is a **function definition**, while method 2 is a **function expression** that is assigned to a variable. Both end up doing the similar thing, but with differences:

- the sequence of events is different (see: hoisting)
- method 2 doesn't set the `name` parameter of the function

Regarding the terminology - "constructor function" is a common term for these:

```
var foo = new Contact();
console.log(foo.constructor === Contact) // true
```

Technically there is nothing special about this functions though. The convention is to capitalise functions that are intended to use as constructors.

Answer (score -1):

Both Method 1 and Method 2 are syntactically correct but Method 1 is like standard when you want to create class in Javascript.

Method 1 give better readability.

Method 2 is good for function variables when you need to pass functions to other parts of the program.

Comment: @user1066946 Question is more in context of object constructors. thank you so much for the link